# Why is it preferred to not use finalize for clean up? .NET

Tags: .net, finalize

(Windows API created objects, File, Database connection objects, COM objects, etc.) are outside the scope of .NET Framework. We have to explicitly clean our resources. For these types of objects, .NET Framework provides *Object.Finalize* method, which can be overridden and clean up code for unmanaged resources...

1. Why is it preferred to not use finalize for clean up?
2. What is appropriate to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred way is to implement `IDisposable` along with the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx). Finalizers are time-limited and the GC will terminate a finalizer if it blocks for too long - this is the primary reason to avoid it where possible.

`Dispose` is just a method call and is not time-limited. The dispose pattern optionally features the finalizer for those situations where the caller forgot to call `Dispose` (as it's not enforced) as a last-ditch attempt to release resources. The pattern also suppresses the finalizer if dispose was called.

The only valid use I have come across with needing a finalizer was for a series of add-ins I wrote for a third party app that didn't raise relevant events for properly managing object life-times. I used the finalizer to make sure I at least attempted to clean stuff up. Other than this I have never relied upon it directly.

`IDisposable` is catered for in C# with the `using` keyword. Anything implementing this interface can be used thus:

```
using (var myDisposableItem = new MyDisposableItem())
{
} // Dispose will be called here for you.
```

So from the calling perspective this is very simple.

<sub>There are various types in the .NET Framework that implement `IDisposable` but have nothing to dispose. I always advise acting as if they need disposing directly because the public contract states they have stuff to dispose, even if the implementation doesn't. Don't program to implementation details.</sub>

Comment: Thx for very good answer. I was wondering, Whats the difference between c++ RAII and IDISPOSABLE?

Comment: @RamizHassan RAII as a concept isn't comparable to `IDisposable`, but to answer the question of what would happen should an exception occur, if you are inside a `using` statement, the `Dispose` method would be called because the compiler generates a `try-finally` for it.

Comment: The point of the C# using statement is to have a nice try finally block around IDisposable code. Take those two things together and we have RAII??

Comment: Your last sentence ("Don't program to implementation details") does not compute when compared to all the classes within .NET that are IDisposable without needing it, because a derived type may need it later, and all those classes that are inherited by an IDisposable object without the parent being IDisposable. The IDisposable interface is an implementation detail. You need to call `using (existingObject as IDisposable) { ... }` to catch all cases of derived implementation being IDisposable, but the documentation (and the implementation) of the parent doesn't mention IDisposable.

Comment: I would say that if a derived class relies on dispose being called in the context of the base class means the public contract has been broken.